# Remove new line only for specific block

Tags: regex, bash, sed, yaml

I have a yaml file that looks like this:

```
user: John Doe
  notes: {
    "a": null,
    "b": null,
    "c": {
      "title": "...",
      "notes": [
        {...}, 
        {...}
      ]
    }
  }
tags: [
  "tag1", 
  "tag2", 
  "tag3"
]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the flattening of the whole block, surrounded by `{}` and `[]`, so that the output at the end looks like this:

```
user: John Doe
  notes: {...}
tags: [...]
```

What I've managed to do so far is this:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\s*//g' test.yml
```

But this flattens the entire yaml content by simply removing all new lines.

Would somebody help me out?

Thanks.

Note: `...` stands for some content, which is in this context not that important. But it definitely must be preserved at the end.

Note 2: The indentation is both for the inner (`{`, `[`) and outer (`}`, `]`) not certain and may actually vary. The yaml content I posted was just an example. The content may also look like this, please take a look at the left side is the input at the right side the desired output: https://jsfiddle.net/u7wbxn8d/2

Note 3: Thanks to @potong, here is the summary of my question:

**The solution must gather up lines for tags that begin at the start of a line and are followed by `:`, while retaining the original indentations.**

(Please see the example in Note 2.)

Comment: You don't want the `{` `}` and `[` `]` in the output only contain `...`, do you?

Comment: Yes. The content must be preserved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of appending lines for a block into the pattern space is feasible; we just have to do this only for a block, i. e. from a line ending with `[` or `{` until a line beginning with `]` or `}`:

```
sed '/[[{]$/{:a;N;/\n[]}]/!ba;s/\n\s*//g}' test.yml
```

> The indentation is both for the inner (`{`, `[`) and outer (`}`, `]`) not certain and may actually vary.

From your fiddle I take that the indentation of the closing `]` or `}` is equal to the indentation of the line with the opening `[` or `{`. Based on that is this `awk` script which works similar to the `sed` script, but in addition handles the indentation by searching the equally indented end of the block:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/[[{]$/ { match($0, /( *)/, space)  # space[1] contains the indentation
          do { printf "%s", $0; getline; t = $0; sub(/ */, "") }
             while (!match(t, "^"space[1]"[]}]"))   # search block end
        }
        { print }   # print simple line as well as last line of block
```

> I get this error, when I run your script `./awk.sh: line 2: syntax error at or near ,`

You have a version of `awk` which doesn't support the third `match()` argument. Here you can replace the `match($0, /( *)/, space)` with `match($0, /( *)/); space[1] = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)`.

> if a closing curly/square bracket doesn't start at a new line your script runs forever and doesn't terminate.

If the brackets are not as regularly placed as the above script assumes, another approach is required. The following script simply counts the bracket nesting level until it reaches zero; in addition it tests for end of file in order to not run forever if the file contains an unclosed block.

```
/[[{]$/ { level = 1 # bracket nesting level
          do { printf "%s", $0; if (!getline) exit 1; sub(/ */, "")
               level += gsub(/[[{]/, "&") - gsub(/[]}]/, "&")
             } while (level)    # search block end
        }
        { print }   # print simple line as well as last line of block
```

Comment: Wow, that looks fantastic. It works almost the way I want it to. But, if the enclosing `]` or `}` also has an indentation, then unfortunately it doesn't work. :(
I know in the example yaml I posted the enclosing ones have no indentation, but it should also work with indentation. Thanks!

Comment: @DenverNuggets - If you'd post an example where it doesn't work, I'd have a look at it.

Comment: @DenverNuggets - Or, could you answer this: Is outermost closing `]` or `}` always indented less then a certain amount, and are inner ones alway indented more?

Comment: The indentation is both for the inner (`{`, `[`) and outer (`}`, `]`) not certain and may actually vary. The yaml content I posted was just an example. The content may also look like this, please take a look at the left side is the input at the right side the desired output: https://jsfiddle.net/u7wbxn8d/2/

Comment: @DenverNuggets - I added a version which should handle the indentations.

Comment: Hey @Armali, thanks a lot for your effort! I really appreciate it! To be clear: The closing curly/square brackets might have different indentation. In my first example the closing one had no indentation, later I said the indentation of both mught vary, but that doesn't mean, the opening and closing one must be absolutely the same. Sorry for the misunderstanding! So, my problem is all about, as soon as an opening curly or square bracket is captured, it should track the content all the way down until it finds the equivalent closing one and flatten the whole block by simply removing the new line.

Comment: Also, please note that I get this error, when I run your script `./awk.sh: line 2: syntax error at or near ,`. Apparently there is something wrong with the first part -> `match($0, /( *)/, arr)`

Comment: @DenverNuggets - Your _jsfiddle_ showed quite well how the indentations are, so the `awk` script can work; I added a change to let it work also with an older `awk` version.

Comment: the `awk` fix worked, thanks a lot!

By the way your solution works well, but if a closing curly/square bracket doesn't start at a new line your script runs forever and doesn't terminate. What I mean is here -> https://jsfiddle.net/98q06ecn/ . When I put the closing `]` right after `"tag3"` in the same line the script runs forever...

Comment: It'ld be really awesome if you could suggest a solution for this problem, since the closing brackets can be simply in the same line and doesn't actually have to start in a new line. Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: @DenverNuggets - I added a version which handles irregular indentations.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to use line-oriented tools like `sed` to try and
change something as complex as YAML. If at any point your input
changes, but is still valid YAML, its regular expression based pattern
matching is likely to break.

You can easily achieve what you want using a YAML parser, e.g. my
`ruamel.yaml` for Python.  Assuming your `test.yaml` changed to be *valid* YAML by replacing
the invalid `{...}`  by `{answer: 42}`

And this `flatten.py`:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

class MyRepresenter(ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter):
    def represent_none(self, data):
        return self.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null', u'null', style='')

MyRepresenter.add_representer(type(None),
                                     MyRepresenter.represent_none)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Representer = MyRepresenter
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.width = 4096  # line width before wrapping
data = yaml.load(sys.stdin)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

running:

```
< test.yaml python flatten.py > out.yaml
```

gives an `out.yaml`:

```
user: John Doe
notes: {"a": null, "b": null, "c": {"title": "...", "notes": [answer: 42, answer: 42]}}
tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
```

You need to provide the special Representer as `null` is normally
represented as the empty scalar (see
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49168538/1307905) answer for
details)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It looks nice and clean! Unfortunately I've to use bash so I only have sed and awk available.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\n\S\+:/!s/\n\s*//;ta;P;D' file
```

This solution gathers up lines for tags that begin at the start of a line and are followed by `:`.

Comment: Hey @potong, sorry for the late reply. Your suggestion actually works! Unfortunately only for the structures where there is no nesting, i.e. for my very first yaml example. 
For this one however it does't work (please refer to HTML section): https://jsfiddle.net/u7wbxn8d/2

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu bash and sed:
Put in your own contents

```
$ CONTENT='contents'  
$ NOTE='notes'
sed -E "/^$NOTE/,/^\}/{/^notes/{s/.*/&$CONTENT\}/;b};d} ;/^tags/,/^\]/{/^tags/{s/.*/&$CONTENT\]/;b};d}" test.yml
```

tried on gnu awk:

```
awk -vf=0 -vNOTE='notes' -vCONTENT='contents' '$0~/^NOTE/||f{f=1;print $0""CONTENT"}";while(getline&&$0!~/^\}/);f=0;next} $0~/^tags/||f{f=1;print $0""CONTENT"]";while(getline&&$0!~/^\]/);f=0;next}1' test.yml
```

Comment: The ``notes` key was just an example. It can be something else. Thus it shouldn't be hard coded in regex. Thanks.